# Use max and filter a list of dicts at the same time

Tags: python

I'm trying to `filter` a list of dicts and at the same time, use the `max` function to get the greatest value from this list based on a key/value:

```
closest_objects = [
    obj for obj in my_list
    if obj['start_date'].date() <= today
]

closest_object = max(
    closest_objects, key=lambda obj: obj['start_date']
)

return closest_object['todo_on_this_date']
```

But I want to know if there is a better way to implement this code if there is the fastest way or a simplified way.

Comment: probably faster, but i've not run any tests/profiling: `import operator as op; max(closest_objects, key=op.itemgetter('start_date'))`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the operator lib, gonna check it right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `filter` and `max` would look something like this:

```
max(
    filter(lambda _: _["start_date"].date() <= today, my_list), 
    key=lambda _: _["start_date"]
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I liked both your approach and @fanfly, there is a difference in performance between the use of filter vs for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator expressions to avoid explicitly construct the filtered list:

```py
closest_object = max((obj for obj in my_list if obj['start_date'].date() <= today),
                     key=lambda obj: obj['start_date'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about this approach, its a simplified version of my code :D